# How to export data from multiple tables into multiple .TXT files in SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to convert multiple tables into multiple .TXT file

I was able to export only one table at a time . Can anyone help on this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use Tools > Database Export.

It's a wizard, on the first page -

[image]

Select 'text' for data output, and multiple files. Then select a directory.

[image]

Proceed to saying if you want tables and view, then optionally select WHICH tables and views you want. If you skip past this page, you'll get EVERY TABLE and EVERY VIEW exported.

Here I can even say, I only want these specific columns or even these specific rows (via a WHERE clause).

After it runs, we get a LOG -

```
** Export Start ** at 2021.08.27-09.23.37
Export Separate Files to /Users/thatjeffsmith/Documents
DATA TABLE ACTIVITIES
File Name: /Users/thatjeffsmith/Documents/ACTIVITIES_DATA_TABLE.tsv
Number of Rows Exported: 513
Elapsed: 00:00:00.382
DATA TABLE EMPLOYEES
File Name: /Users/thatjeffsmith/Documents/EMPLOYEES_DATA_TABLE.tsv
Number of Rows Exported: 108
Elapsed: 00:00:00.095
DATA TABLE SPOTIFY
File Name: /Users/thatjeffsmith/Documents/SPOTIFY_DATA_TABLE.tsv
Number of Rows Exported: 8557
Elapsed: 00:00:00.633
Total Elapsed: 00:00:01.128
/Users/thatjeffsmith/Documents/
/Users/thatjeffsmith/Documents/Generated-20210827092337.sql
** Export End ** at 2021.08.27-09.23.38
```

And of course, we also expect our files, voila.

[image]